# Three.js: Raycast intersection on Line with BufferGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting, buffer-geometry

Since R59 raycasting on lines is possible and it works perfect. I'm displaying a tooltip on mouseover.

Because of growing data, I had performance issues, so I decided to switch from `THREE.Geometry` to `THREE.BufferGeometry`. Everything works fine instead of raycasting.... I get no errors or something else on mouseover, there happens really nothing!

Isn't it possible to intersect raycasting on a line which was build up with `THREE.BufferGeometry`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,`Raycaster` supports `Line` with `BufferGeometry`.

Be aware of the `threshold` parameter described in the [docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster.params).

See https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_lines.html

three.js r.130

Comment: That's what I supposed to hear ... :( Do you know if there is someone working on that? Or should I open a suggestion on github?

Comment: After updating on r60 I'm getting errors:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined threeR60.js:7047
intersectObject threeR60.js:7047
intersectDescendants threeR60.js:7086
THREE.Raycaster.intersectObject`
maybe someone should fix this

Comment: If you can demonstrate a bug, you can help by reporting it. Please see the three.js [guidelines](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) for How to Report a Bug.